# Dynamically include css or Js file using php

Tags: php, gulp

Every time Gulp changes the CSS or JS files it keep the output file name same as before. How will browser know that file has been changed and need to reload the css and JS files?

To resolve this problem, I am decide to use the following Gulp plugin:

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev

it rename the assets file by appending content hash to filenames

```
unicorn.css => unicorn-098f6bcd.css
```

is there any way to include the assets file using php dynamically? Assets name will change every time when new content added.

Comment: simple solution , try appending a random variable to the css url ie ,unicorn.css?no_cache=<?php echo time();?>Not recommended , but a work around

Comment: Not a good idea. Browser will load the assets in every requests.

Comment: @aman yes agreed totally , I said work around

Comment: Why don't you just configure your server to use E-Tags or Last Modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to include file dynamically. its fast (takes about 1.5 ms) and working perfectly.

PHP has a native function (glob) for searching files. According to PHP docs "*The glob() function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the libc glob() function, which is similar to the rules used by common shells.*"

**glob()**

```
// css path would be the full physical path of your css directory
$cssPath = '/css/*.css';
$stylesheets = glob($cssPath, GLOB_NOSORT);

// link all stylesheets
<?php foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet): ?>

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/<?=basename($stylesheet)?>">

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead renaming file, you can send finger print with it. if file changes, last modified changes too. so you can easily use file's last modified as finger print:

```
public function putStyle($fileName)
{
    $fp = filemtime($fileName); // finger print by file last modified
    $fileName .= '?' . $fp;
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $fileName . '"/>';
}
```

Comment: Good idea.However, I am trying to avoid query string because the CDN will see that GET parameter and think that its a dynamic request, so it will ask your servers for the file, which defeats the purpose of having a cached copy in the CDN.