# How do I replace the filenames listed in index.html with the output of gulp-rev?

Tags: gulp

I'm using [gulp-rev](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-rev/) to build static files that I can set to [never expire](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires). I'd like to replace all references to the generated files in index.html to these renamed files, but I can't seem to find anything that does that like Grunt with usemin.

As far as I can tell right now, I have some options.

1. Use [gulp-usemin2](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-usemin2), which depends on gulp-rev. When I go to search [Gulp plugins](http://gulpjs.com/plugins/), it says that gulp-usemin2 does too much so I should use [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-useref/) instead, but I can't configure gulp-ref to use gulp-rev's output.
2. Write my own plugin the replace the blocks (scripts & styles) in index.html (and in the CSS) with the generated files.

Any ideas? I don't see why this little use case should be the only thing in my way to replacing Grunt.

Comment: You can use `gulp-inject`, which I've described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072880/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-the-html-to-use-gulp-minified-css/21249167#21249167

Answer (score 13):

Rather than trying to solve this problem multiple gulp steps (which gulp-rev seems to want you to do), I've forked gulp-rev to [gulp-rev-all](https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all) to solve this usecase in one gulp plugin.

For my personal usecase I wanted to rev absolutely everything but as someone else raised an feature request, there should be the ability to exclude certain files like index.html.  This will be implemented soon.

Comment: gulp-rev-all does exactly this!

Comment: gulp-rev-all indeed appears to be the only reasonable solution for this problem.

Answer (score 11):

I've just written a [gulp plugin](https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace) to do this, it works especially well with gulp-rev and gulp-useref.

The usage will depend on how you've set things up, but it should look something like:

```
gulp.task("index", function() {
  var jsFilter = filter("**/*.js");
  var cssFilter = filter("**/*.css");

  return gulp.src("src/index.html")
    .pipe(useref.assets())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(uglify())             // Process your javascripts
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(csso())               // Process your CSS
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe(rev())                // Rename *only* the concatenated files
    .pipe(useref.restore())
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(revReplace())         // Substitute in new filenames
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Comment: oohh, trying this now... does it work with watch? like would it continue to run in the background without throwing an error? Also can you add an example where you you use sass with rev?

Comment: there's a problem with useref - it doesn't work on gulp.watch (faceplam)

Comment: I really appreciate the separation here. It'd be nice to get this integrated into useref itself.

Comment: Can you please update to use the latest API from useref? I'm trying to update to the latest version of these modules and it is also renaming index.html. I would like to stop that from happening.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as @dale.lotts - would like to run rev/rev-replace without renaming my index.html

Comment: dale.lotts and Kevin here is an example in the README of gulp-rev-replace https://github.com/jamesknelson/gulp-rev-replace

Answer (score 5):

I have confronted the same problem, I tried gulp-rev-all, but it has some path problem, not very free to use.

So I figure out an solution, use gulp-rev and [gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace):

**At first I have a replace symbol in my html(js, css) files**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{{css/common.css}}}" />

<script src="{{{js/lib/jquery.js}}}"></script>
```

in css files

```
background: url({{{img/logo.png}}})
```

**Second after some compile task, use gulp-replace to replace all the static files reference:**

take stylus compile in development as example:

```
gulp.task('dev-stylus', function() {
   return gulp.src(['./fe/css/**/*.styl', '!./fe/css/**/_*.styl'])
             .pipe(stylus({
               use: nib()
             }))
             .pipe(replace(/\{\{\{(\S*)\}\}\}/g, '/static/build/$1'))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/build/css'))
             .pipe(refresh());
});
```

**In production environment, use gulp-rev to generate rev-manifest.json**

```
gulp.task('release-build', ['release-stylus', 'release-js', 'release-img'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['./static/build/**/*.css',
                   './static/build/**/*.js',
                   './static/build/**/*.png',
                   './static/build/**/*.gif',
                   './static/build/**/*.jpg'],
                   {base: './static/build'})
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/tmp'))
             .pipe(rev())
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/tmp'))
             .pipe(rev.manifest())
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./static'));
});
```

**Then use gulp-replace to replace the refs in static files with rev-manifest.json:**

```
gulp.task('css-js-replace', ['img-replace'], function() {
  return gulp.src(['./static/tmp/**/*.css', './static/tmp/**/*.js'])
             .pipe(replace(/\{\{\{(\S*)\}\}\}/g, function(match, p1) {
               var manifest = require('./static/rev-manifest.json');
               return '/static/dist/'+manifest[p1]
             }))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This helped me [gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace).

```
 <!-- build:js -->
    <script src="js/player.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/monster.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/world.js"></script> 
<!-- endbuild -->
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

    gulp.task('default', function() {
      gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'css': 'styles.min.css',
            'js': 'js/bundle.min.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with gulp-useref like this.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    useref = require('gulp-useref'),
    filter = require('gulp-filter'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev');

gulp.task('html', function () {
    var jsFilter = filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref.assets())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe(useref.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

or you could even do it this way:

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
    var jsFilter = filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref.assets())
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
        .pipe(cssFilter)
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
        .pipe(useref.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The problem is updating the asset paths in the html with the new rev file paths. gulp-useref doesn't do that.

Comment: yeah, i need it to update with the rev paths. it adds no value to me to do anything less.