# Gulp-Rev-replace not replacing my the file path with the gulp-rev hash

Tags: gulp

Similar to this question here: [How do I replace the filenames listed in index.html with the output of gulp-rev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359464/how-do-i-replace-the-filenames-listed-in-index-html-with-the-output-of-gulp-rev)

Im using gulp-useref to combine the files listed in my build blocks.  I would like to use gulp-rev to add a hash to the end of the concatenated file and update my markup with the new filename.

As per the gulp-rev-replace doc, im using this almost exactly with minor tweaks:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var RevAll = require('gulp-rev-all');


gulp.task("index", function () {
    var jsFilter = filter("js/**/*.js");
    var cssFilter = filter("css/**/*.css");
    var revAll = new RevAll();
    var userefAssets = useref.assets();

    return gulp.src("Views/**/*.cshtml")
      .pipe(userefAssets)      // Concatenate with gulp-useref 
      .pipe(jsFilter)
      .pipe(uglify())             // Minify any javascript sources 
      .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
      .pipe(cssFilter)
      .pipe(csso())               // Minify any CSS sources 
      .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
      .pipe(rev())                // Rename the concatenated files 
      .pipe(userefAssets.restore())
      .pipe(useref())
      .pipe(revReplace())         // Substitute in new filenames 
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

my html looks like so:

```
<!-- build:css css/combined.css -->
<link href="css/components/style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/components/style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/pages/style3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js js/lib.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/global/js1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/components/component.calendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages/jaunt-hotels/matrix.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

the output I get is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/combined.css">
<script src="js/lib.js">
the </script>
```

but what im looking for is something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/combined-ABC234.css">
<script src="js/lib-TYU765.js"></script>
```

directory structure:

```
root
 |-css
    |-style1.css
    |-style2.css
    |-style3.css
 |-js
    |-*js files here
 |-views
    |-*Many folders with .cshtml files
 |-gulp
    |-tasks
        |-bundle-assets.js  <-  task that contains code above
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm worried about revAll, since you don't use it in your pipeline. Can you explain why you need this plugin?

Comment: Another question: Are those JS files and CSS files in the output directory? Related: Can you show me how your file structure is? When userefAssets can't read the assets, it won't create any files, thus rev and rev-replace can't work

Comment: ddprrt - Ive updated my code with gulp-rev-replace, as it was a typo.  been actually trying to use both but could not get either of them to work. Thanks!  If you know of a better way to get concated-minified-rev'd file names into their corresponding html files, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question! I tried your Gulp-Setup yesterday and found out, that the useref and rev plugin's won't work if the path to your assets are incorrect. In your sample, the `*.cshtml` files are all in the folder `views`, but pointing to ressources which are on one level above. Going from a file inside `views` (like `views/index.cshtml`, the path `css/components/style1.css` cannot be resolved, because it should actually be `../css/components/style1.css`. Therefore `useref` gets an empty resultset, does not create any files, and `rev` cannot update because it has no point to reference to.

Get the paths in your `cshtml` right so that they're relative to the real ressources, than it will work. I hope you can because that setup looks a little Dotnetty, and I'm not sure if you have freedom there to change things ;-)

Comment: yes it is very .netty.  With visual studio 2015 coming down pushing gulp/grunt tasks, we're trying to get ahead of the curve and just move over.

Comment: Got the files paths updated, and the css/js are now being properly compiled and rev'd into their respective folders. Almost there!  Now just need a rev-replace to update the filepaths in the html to point to the new rev'd files...which it doesnt do.  Is rev-replace the right plugin to use? open to any other route as well.

Comment: ddprrt - Got it working.  Realized that rev-replace has and option `replaceInExtensions` that I needed to add cshtml to.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Can You please share the complete gulf working file, i am also looking the same type of result like below.
the output I get is:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/combined.css">
<script src="js/lib.js">
the </script>
but what im looking for is something like:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/combined-ABC234.css">
<script src="js/lib-TYU765.js"></script>

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass an option to `revReplace()`, like so:

`.pipe(revReplace({replaceInExtensions: ['.cshtml']}));`

By default, `gulp-rev-replace` will perform changes only on `['.js', '.css', '.html', '.hbs']`.

More information on https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-replace#options-replaceinextensions.

I was working with `.ejs` and had a similar issue.  Hope this helps..

Comment: I cannot find words to describe my gratitude. I've been fighting for hours changing versions and everything trying to figure out why rev-replace won't work and it was the extension!